Grub Splash/Background obscured by menu
I have just set up Grub to show a Background image but it appears obscured by another menu:

As you can see, the background is still showing along the edges but the main Grub menu obscures it.
Here are my config files:

/etc/default/grub (I removed comments to make it smaller):
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=7 splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="zswap.enabled=0 rootfstype=ext4"
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="n"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="countdown"
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="gfxterm"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="false"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="false"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="n"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"

GRUB_BACKGROUND="/root/Documents/grub.jpg"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="black/blue"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/brown"


/etc/grub.d/06_grub-customizer_menu_color_helper (created by Grub-Customizer):
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x${GRUB_BACKGROUND}" != "x" ] ; then
        if [ "x${GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL}" != "x" ] ; then
        echo "set color_normal=${GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL}"
        fi

        if [ "x${GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT}" != "x" ] ; then
        echo "set color_highlight=${GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT}"
        fi
fi


/etc/grub.d/41_custom (also created by Grub-Customizer):
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF
if [ -f  \${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "\${config_directory}" -a -f  \$prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source \$prefix/custom.cfg
fi 
EOF




export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="black/blue" ... maybe change the blue to something that is transparent. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays says black in background == transparent, so black/black

As @muru said in the comments, I had to change the line export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="black/blue" in /etc/default/grub to say (any color)/black.

Why do I have to wait 2 days to accept my answer?

It's a restriction for new users, since many of them mistakenly post answers meant to be edits and accept them
